# Some imported command names contain one or more of the following restricted characters

Tags: powershell

Using my own Powershell script module in Octopus, Octopus is warning that

```
WARNING: Some imported command names contain one or more of the following restricted characters: # , ( ) {{ }} [ ] & - / \ $ ^ ; : " ' < > | ? @ ` * % + = ~
```

The script module looks like this

```
function complete-iis-config($poolAndSitenameFilter)
{
 # do stuff
}

export-modulemember -function complete-iis-config
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is because I used a hyphen twice. The `Verb-Noun` PowerShell guideline means there should only be one hyphen.

Renaming my function to `Complete-IisConfig` cleared the warning

Comment: You can also use the "-DisableNameChecking" flag when importing your module. Sometimes, there are good reasons not to follow rules and conventions. Not often, though.